# ¿Cómo guardar el archivo con el nombre del doc?

Tags: perl, google-documentos

Tengo un script en Perl que si le ingresas la url de un google docs lo descarga, pero el problema es que lo guarda con el nombre gdown siempre, como puedo hacer que lo guarde con el nombre del documento de google docs?

```perl
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
#
# Google Drive direct download of big files
# ./gdown.pl 'gdrive file url' ['desired file name']
#
# v1.0 by circulosmeos 04-2014.
# v1.1 by circulosmeos 01-2017.
# http://circulosmeos.wordpress.com/2014/04/12/google-drive-direct-download-of-big-files
# Distributed under GPL 3 (http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html)
#
use strict;

my $TEMP='gdown.cookie.temp';
my $COMMAND;
my $confirm;
my $check;
sub execute_command();

my $URL=shift;
die "\n./gdown.pl 'gdrive file url' [desired file name]\n\n" if $URL eq '';

my $FILENAME=shift;
$FILENAME='gdown' if $FILENAME eq '';

if ($URL=~m#^https?://drive.google.com/file/d/([^/]+)#) {
    $URL="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=$1&export=download";
}

execute_command();

while (-s $FILENAME < 100000) { # only if the file isn't the download yet
    open fFILENAME, '<', $FILENAME;
    $check=0;
    foreach (<fFILENAME>) {
        if (/href="(\/uc\?export=download[^"]+)/) {
            $URL='https://docs.google.com'.$1;
            $URL=~s/&amp;/&/g;
            $confirm='';
            $check=1;
            last;
        }
        if (/confirm=([^;&]+)/) {
            $confirm=$1;
            $check=1;
            last;
        }
        if (/"downloadUrl":"([^"]+)/) {
            $URL=$1;
            $URL=~s/\\u003d/=/g;
            $URL=~s/\\u0026/&/g;
            $confirm='';
            $check=1;
            last;
        }
    }
    close fFILENAME;
    die "Couldn't download the file :-(\n" if ($check==0);
    $URL=~s/confirm=([^;&]+)/confirm=$confirm/ if $confirm ne '';

    execute_command();
}

unlink $TEMP;

sub execute_command() {
    $COMMAND="wget --no-check-certificate --load-cookie $TEMP --save-cookie $TEMP \"$URL\"";
    $COMMAND.=" -O \"$FILENAME\"" if $FILENAME ne '';
    `$COMMAND`;
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

¿No está indicado en el propio comentario del principio? Debes indicar el nombre del archivo a continuación de la URL a descargar.

Es lo que veo del código, que funciona así: es el segundo argumento del programa.

Comment: Si pero lo que yo quiero es que obtenga el nombre desde la url, es decir, el nombre del archivo en Google docs

Comment: Si la URL coincide con la expresión regular que hay en el primer if(), te vale con agregar una línea

$FILENAME=$1;

justo antes de la llave de cierre de ese if().